# Golden gate replication table's trigger failed to call package

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

Receiving  "ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called" when a trigger on a replication table tries to call a package.

The same code was working fine at first and it is failing later.
And the package is valid and we have all grants in place. Also we tried dropping and recreating both the trigger and the package including the grants. Still facing same error.
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trace the behavior in Oracle Database. You can use the 10046 trace to list all SQL commands that GoldenGate is issuing. Extract the commands from the trace and run them manually on the target database. You should be able to see the same error and be able to track the source of it.

Comment: We found the issue, we need to enable trigger suppress option, which is done by DBA. only for golden gate tables this option is mandatory to enable then only we can place triggers on those table. Technically this is done by DBA, so just updated the comments.thank you